# JavaScript throws RuntimeBinderException: while using JSON.parse for Model

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I was working on Razor page with MVC. I want to get model values in Javascript to update the table dynamically.
I am using below code to pass index dynamically.

```
var page1 = JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList["+ i +"]))");
```

But it throws error as

> RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,object>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments.

Instead of double quotes I have tried with single quotes as below

```
var page1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList['+ i +']))');
```

But in this case I'm getting synatx error

> Too many characters in character literal

If I use hardcoded index it is working perfectly:

```
var page1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[0]))');
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes stands for string values and single quotes stands for character values in Razor pages.
You can try to use backtick template literals to pass index dynamically

```
var page1 = JSON.parse(`@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[${i}]))`);
```

Comment: Getting error as variable i doesnt exist and unexpected char $

Comment: are you declaring i variable in for loop ? are you using the backtick symbols ?

Comment: Hi @shubhkr1, Yes I m using i variable in for loop. I have used the code what you have given above but still not working

Comment: The backtick [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is a JavaScript format. Its use is within a JavaScript context. It's used incorrectly here as `@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[i]))` needs to execute in the context of the Razor engine and C# on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The original line of code in your post:

`var page1 = JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList["+ i +"]))");`

looks like an attempt to write `"@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList["+ i +"]))"` as a string into the HTML content stream that will be processed on the client. You're concatenating three strings together: `"@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList["` linked with the value of the variable `i` linked with `"]))"`.

The following will be processed correctly in a Razor page.

```
let page1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[i]))');
```

assuming the variable 'i' is defined within a Razor syntax (e.g. `int i = 1; }`).

Breaking down the above line of code:

`JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[i])` is C# code processed on the server when the Razor page is parsed.

The Razor engine then uses `@Html.Raw()` to render the string result from `JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.conditionList[i])` into the HTML content stream. The content stream is added to the HTTP response that's sent to the client.

After the client browser parses and renders the HTML in the response, the JavaScript engine executes the `JSON.parse()` method on the serialized string embedded within the parenthesis of the `JSON.parse()` method. For example:

```
JSON.parse('[\"abc\",\"def\"]');
```